# Ужасный интерпретатор Python 3.6 не хочет ничего делать

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кто-нибудь, помогите пожалуйста. 
Интерпретатор на Python - вещь страшная. Это я уже давно понял,
но сейчас просто он не хочет работать.

1) У всех работает команда:

```
print os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

А у меня нет.

2) И ещё **os.listdir()** не видит указанную директорию. Просто пишет, что не правильно указана.

Что с ним вообще творится?

Comment: print в третьем питоне требует скобок вокруг аргумента. В остальном ваша проблема не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 4):

В третьем питоне команда `print os.listdir(os.getcwd())` ни у кого не работает. В третьем питоне после print требуются скобки вокруг аргументов:

```
import os    
print (os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```